# IE intranet compatibility issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iis, intranet

I have two sites hosted on an intranet network.
One site loads absolutely fine in IE11 without changing the compatibility mode.
but
when I open my other application in IE11. the IE automatically switches the Document mode to 7. Notifying Intranet compatibility settings.
I have included the doctype also.  which is fine

I tried adding X-UA-compatibility meta tag which solved the issue. but in my previous web app, i haven't included any such meta tag and still it renders fine.

I want to render my new application without the meta tag.
How can i do it. ?

Comment: Have you definied <meta charset="UTF-8"> on your HTML's pages ?

Comment: In my previous site which renders properly
I have <br>
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?-->
and <br>
<body xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
and nothing else.

Comment: HTML1202: http://webserver:8085/home.html is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.
This is the message i receive in console when i run my new app. but i dont get any such message in my old app.

Comment: what are the other ways to override the intranet compatibility settings